# awk evaluate variable in statement

Tags: awk, variable, variable-substitution

I am new to `awk`, I tried numerous suggestion found online, but I cannot resolve my problem.
I need variable `$number` to get evaluated inside the -F arg value.

This statement works as expected:

```
inn=$(ip ad)     
vth=$(echo $inn | awk -F ' 6: |@' '{print $2}')
echo $vth
```

but I need to extract this "6" and change its value accordingly, how do I do this?

This is my best guess, but it is not working:

```
     inn=$(ip ad) 
     vth=$(echo $inn | awk -vn="$number" -F ' n: |@' '{print $2}')
     echo $vth
```

Update:
I tried the solution, provided by @Archemar.

It works great in console, but when I add it in the file, it does not work? why? how does the evaluation of the variable differs between **.sh** file and executing directly in **console**?

EDIT: 1) added $inn
2) the difference between executing in console and .sh file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this rather look a shell problem, have you tried .. ?

```
vth=$(echo "$inn" | awk -F ' '"$number"': |@' '{print $2}')
```

- be sure to have your shell as a bash (e.g. first line is `#!/bin/bash` )
- if you don't need `$inn` elsewhere, use `vth=$( ip ad | ... )`
- I can't reproduce `@` in result of `ip a s` (or `ip ad` )

to catch lan interface name number `$number` I would use

```
vth=$(ip a s | awk -F'[: @]' -v n="$number" '$1 == n { print $3 ; exit; }' )
```

---

Note that result of `ip a s` is not meant to be parsable.

there is a `-j` option in `ip` to produce a json script that might be easier to parse with `jq` utility.

Comment: ok, this worked in console, but it didn't in my .sh file, why?
in the script, I've got:
 ` echo $number
  inn=$(ip ad)

  veth=$(echo $inn | awk -F ' '$number': |@' '{print $2}')
  echo $veth`

Comment: the results with "@" come from the virtual eths that I have.

Comment: almost there! the virtual lan interfaces come as name@if, like: vethdcdae4f@if5. with your last edit, I can get the whole string, but I need it only up to the "@if5". how do I do that?

Comment: what finally did the trick was chaining another awk, like:
vth=$(ip a s | awk -F: -v n=$number '$1 == n { print $2}' ) | awk -F '@' '{print $1}'

Comment: please, do not pipe `awk` into `awk` it hurts (me at least), I think FS should be `'[: @]'` ans field to be print is 3.

Comment: thanks a lot! great! as soon as I can vote up I will! thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Use a `BEGIN` block:

```
awk -v n="$number" 'BEGIN {FS=" " n ": |@"}'
```

So yours become:

```
vth=$(echo "$inn" | awk -v n="$number" 'BEGIN {FS=" " n ": |@"} {print $2}')
```

Comment: I get no result at all? what is FS? are you sure about the "" marks?

Comment: @gai-jin: setting `FS` in the same as calling `awk` with `-F`

Comment: as soon as I can vote up, I'll vote